# Sharing virtualmachines between windows and linux hosts. What filesystem do I need?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine

In my current setup I'm using both Windows and Linux hosts, I've a bunch of VM in a partition and I need to use and access them from either hosts.

I've tested a couple of filesystems with very poor results:

- `NTFS`: on linux the NTFS implementation runs in usermode with fuse and it's unbelievable slow, the VM runs at 1fps and the whole host system is thrashing.
- `exFAT`: same as NTFS
- `FAT32`: It seems to work well but the lack of journal and other features scares me a bit and I don't know if it's a good idea to keep VM there

Is there a more intelligent way to shares VMs betweens two hosts?

Comment: Consider using native partitions for your VMs.

Comment: @mspasov raw partitions are a feature only available for VMware Workstation, aren't they?

Comment: VMware Workstation, Player and VirtualBox all support raw disks/partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use FAT32 with a preallocated/2G split VMDK and have never had problems: The point being, that the metadata on the file system never changes (apart from file times) - this mitigates most of FAT32's weaknesses - running FAT32 with any growing file is a risk you might or might not be willing to take.

What remains is FAT32's lack of access permissions - you will have to decide, whether that's a show-stopper.

Comment: Right now I'm using FAT32 with 2G VMDK split but they are growing and not preallocated. What risks can I face using this setup instead of a preallocated VMDK files?

Comment: Growing VMDKs do involve the weaknesses of FAT - metadata updates, fragmentation etc. For me, the loss of thin provisioning is more acceptable than that.